# my internet dies if another computer is turned on, how do i fix this?

Tags: windows-7, internet

I just bought a new laptop it runs on windows 7.  I live at my parents’ house and our family has 3 computers, my laptop running windows 7, my mom’s new computer running windows 7, and my dad’s old computer running windows XP.  We just moved here and we got a new internet it is cable with perfectly fine speed I don’t know the exact specifications but it can stream video and download large files quickly etc.  so the problem is when I’m using my laptop the internet works fine, if my DAD turns his computer on, my internet works fine, however if my mom turns her computer on my internet slows WAY down to the point that websites take about 2  minutes to load, or my internet will completely crash.  My laptop is wireless, my mom and dad’s computers are both plugged directly into the router and neither of them are actually using the internet, my mom just plays solitaire, but for some reason if my mom’s computer is turned on I get no internet. Please help how do I fix this?

Comment: What kind of router? Does your connection break? Can you ping google.com? *more details* would help us help you better.

Comment: Does your mothers PC being turned on impact internet speed on your dads PC?  If so, make sure AV is up to date and scan your mothers PC.

Comment: @Paul A virus was my first guess as well.

Answer (score 3):

Vincent,

The problem you are having might be caused by both Static and Dynamic IP addressing being used at the same time on your home network, and the static IP addresses (you, or your parents are setting manually) are running into the same addresses provided by your local DHCP server.

The collisions occur because the DHCP server (dynamic addressing) has no knowledge of manually/statically assigned IP addresses that are configured on computers.

The first alternative to get around this problem is to make each computer only get their IP addresses from the DHCP server (usually the same device that you use to connect to the internet at home).

The second alternative is to set IP reservations (which is more complicated than the first alternative) but this would tell the DHCP server to not issue out that particular IP address that is you are choosing to 'reserve' for a specific computer. You would only use this option if some of the computers on your network are sharing things to other computers on the network (files, programs etc.)

For every computer on your home network, can you please open the command prompt and type ipconfig /all and see if any of the network adapters listed have the line 'DHCP enabled.....Yes'?
If one of them is, can you please let us know and also include the make and model of the device you use to connect to the internet?

This will help us advise you on how to configure your local DHCP server.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling ethernet controller on your mom's pc then check if internet works on your pc  if it works then there is a virus problem or some software tries to connect to internet with too many connections. Most of the slow down problems are because of the messy routing table in router. Also try setting Maximum ports on router to 4096 and UDP timeouts to 90. If your router don't allow to do it then if you’ve replaced your router’s fi rmware with the Open Source [DD-WRT firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com), you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check under this circumstances is what ip addresses is used in your network and how your machines are mapped. By your words it seems that you with your mom share one single ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your mom's Windows 7 is downloading a large Windows/Office update? Check Networking tab on Resource Monitor or Task manager. Otherwise, I'll go with @super_sonic answer.